Why specifying values on a local section is enough to determine the local values of a tensorial form on a principal $G$-bundle?
Let $\pi: E \rightarrow B$ be a principal $G$-bundle.
I have an initial context from which my question comes and I will explain how; I believe what I need is more general, but I may be wrong, and this is why I am explaining the context. So, in my context $G = GL(n, \mathbb R)$ and  $\theta \in \Omega^1(E, \mathbb R^n)$ is a tensorial $\mathbb R^n$-valued $1$-form i.e. it vanishes on vertical vectors and $\theta \circ R_{g, *} = g^{-1} \circ \theta$ for any $g \in G$. Suppose on some open set $U$ of $B$ we have a section $\sigma: U \rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U)$. I am trying to see why $\theta$ is defined on $U$ only by the values it takes on the image of $\sigma_*$. By tensoriality, we have for any $X \in T_p E$ and $g \in G$ that $\theta(R_{g,*} X) = g^{-1} \theta(X)$. Hence, we would be done if we could write any $X \in T_p E$ as $X = R_{g,*} \sigma_{\pi(p), *}(Y)$ + some vertical part, for some $g \in G$ and $Y \in T_{\pi(p)} B$.
This is what makes me think that my question is more general, namely:

If $G$ is any Lie group and $\pi, U, \sigma$ are as before, can we write any $X \in T_p E$ as $X = R_{g, *} \sigma_{\pi(p), *} (Y)$ + a vertical part?

My idea was to take a curve $c(t) \in E$ tangent to $X$ at $t=0$ and use that $\sigma$ is a section, so that we have $g(t) \in G$ with $c(t) = R_{g(t)} \circ \sigma \circ \pi \circ c(t)$.
Then taking the function
$$
F(s,t) = R_{g(s)} \circ \sigma \circ \pi \circ c(t)
$$
we have:
\begin{align*}
d_{(t,s)} F(\frac{d}{dt}) &=
R_{g(s), *} \sigma_* (\pi_* X)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
d_{(t,s)} F(\frac{d}{ds}) &=
\frac{d}{ds} 
\left( 
(s \mapsto g(s)) \circ (g \mapsto R_g ( \sigma \pi c(t) ) 
\right)
= d(g \mapsto R_g(\sigma(\pi(c(t)))) \left( \frac{d}{ds} (g(s)) \right)
\end{align*}
So then, taking $g=g(0)$ and $Y = \pi_* X$, we have:
$$
X = \frac{d}{dt} (t \mapsto F(t,t))
= R_{g,*} \sigma_*(Y) + d(g \mapsto R_g(\sigma(\pi(p))) \left( \frac{d}{dt} (g(t))\rvert_{t=0} \right)
$$
So the first term is precisely what I want, but I have no clue what to do with the second! Is it possible to show that that monstrosity is a vertical vector? Or to make choices so that it is so?

Staring at it again, it is not only possible to show that the monstrosity is vertical, it is in fact trivial to show that, just by applying $\pi_*$ to it and using $\pi \circ R_g = \pi$.
